# Getting Values of Object from a variable

Tags: javascript, object

I have created a data sharing function, one to pass variables and one that gets these values as object as below.

```
var paramsObj = {};
var dataShareProvider = () => {
    return {
        getProperty: function () {
            return {
                paramsObj,
            };
        },
        setProperty: function (pKey1, pKey2, pKey3, pKey4, pKey5) {
            paramsObj.pKey1 = pKey1;
            paramsObj.pKey2 = pKey2;
            paramsObj.pKey3 = pKey3;
            paramsObj.pKey4 = pKey4;
            paramsObj.pKey5 = pKey5;
        },
    };
};
```

This is how i set the property values from a function.

```
dataShareProvider().setProperty(7, "active", true);
```

And i can access it another function as below

```
var userData = dataShareProvider().getProperty().paramsObj;

console.log(userData)
```

I need a small help in accessing values of objects. In my browser console, the values are as below
[image]

I need values of pKey1, pKey2 and pKey3 to be used. I tried to it below but it gives me undefined

```
console.log(userData.pKey1) ==> undefined
```

Comment: How do you want `paramsObj` object to look like after you call `dataShareProvider().setProperty(...)` with specific properties?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/zeyuzokoya/1/edit?js,console). With that said, this seems like an awfully complex setup for just sharing some values.

Comment: It works on my end too. For me, it's incorrect setting of console-level in chrome dev tool, **Info** level must be enabled to show the value of console.log.

Comment: @Max, This is my expectation `const userData= {pKey1: 7, pKey2: true, pKey3: true}` so that i can just access values like `userData.pKey1 or userData.pKey2` etc...

Comment: I mean, you can do that already... Probably, you want to completely override the `paramsObj` object using `{ setSaramsObj(value) { paramsObj = value } }`, and calling `dataShareProvider().setSaramsObj({ pKey: 7, pKey2: true }).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try It:

```js
var paramsObj = {};
var dataShareProvider = () => {
    return {
        getProperty: () => window.paramsObj,
        setProperty: (...pKey) => pKey.forEach((value, index) => window.paramsObj[`pKey${index +1}`] = value)
    }
};

dataShareProvider().setProperty(7, "active", true);
const userData = dataShareProvider().getProperty();
console.log("pKey1: ", userData.pKey1) // output: 7
console.log("pKey2: ", userData.pKey2) // output: "active"
console.log("pKey3: ", userData.pKey3) // output: true
```